# White page in WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I've moved my wordpress based website from a CentOS server to my windows web server 2008 R2. I imported the database from phpmyadmin and when i try to view my website in browser i see a blank white page.

Check www.servergeek.ro

Comment: Please add this line to wp-config.php (in your WordPress root) define('WP_DEBUG', true); and see if you have any errors.

Comment: nothing changed. I can see all of my articles in dashbord and i also can log into wordpress dashbord. The only problem is the home page because it shows a blank page.

Comment: You can access the Admin Page? If you can try and Update your Permalinks. Or try to add Activate another Theme.

Comment: Yes, the problem was from that Permalinks. I've changed to the default structure and now it works. How can i use my custom structure /%postname%/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well try to update again with `/%postname%/` that should fix it. If is not fixed, check your **Apache Server** if **mod_rewrite** is available and activated.

Comment: It almost works. If i try to acces an article i recive 404 error and all of my images are gone.

Comment: I use IIS 7,5 and i don't have apache or something like it :)

Comment: This should have been posted as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress permalinks work thanks to address rewrite, if you switched from apache to a windows web server you'll have to adapt `.htaccess` to its syntax.

Comment: I have Helicon Ape which is an Apache Emulator i guess and i have there a .htaccess file. I've put the rewrite code from wordpress dashbord in that .htacces file but it dosen't works.

Comment: I've created a web.config file instead of .htaccess file and it works. I have only one problem now. All of my images are gone. I mean the images from the first part of the articles, that part before < more > tag.

Comment: I re-uploaded the "uploads" folder with all the images and it works fine. Thanks guys. That was great tech support. Have a great day.

Comment: This should have probably been posted as a comment.